# Magento 2 system configuration image file upload into my custom directory with the size validation

Tags: magento2, image, validation, system.xml

I am working a Magento Extension, as per my requirement I've to upload an image from the system configuration field.

I have done the image upload, once the image uploaded the file stored in (root/pub/media/MY_DIR).
But instead of upload into the root directory, I've to upload the icon into my Namespace/Module/View/adminhtml/web/images/MY_DIR. Also, I have to validate the file size.

I've gone through some blog, but it couldn't help me to accomplish the task. I need a better approach to do the functionality.

Thanks in advance for your support.